# Azure Mobile Service Paging Limitation

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I have a query function that talks to a local Azure mobile service (localhost). I am aware that the default query limitation is 50, and the official document says the `Take` extension function could be used to extend the limitation up to 1000. But for some reason it does not work for me, no matter how many the `Take` parameter is, I always got 50 objects back. Am I doing anything wrong?

```
private async void UpdatePlaceNameList(String type)
    {
        var table = App.MobileService.GetTable<Place>();
        var query = table
            .Where(p => p.Type == type)
            .Take(600)
            .IncludeTotalCount();
        ViewModel["PlaceList"] = await query.ToListAsync();
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Against the .NET backend there is a server imposed limit of 50 that works a little differently from what the docs say (those apply to the Node.js backend)

The .NET backend returns a default limit 50 records at a time.  To override that you need to add a Queryable(MaxTop) to your getAll function in your backend code like so:

**Original Answer**

```
[Queryable(MaxTop = 1000)]
public IQueryable<Place> GetAll()
```

**Update 1: 6/5/2018**

The original answer is now marked obsolete, use the following code instead:

```
[EnableQuery(MaxTop = 1000)]
public IQueryable<Place> GetAll()
```

--

This will now let you get up to X records at a time.

Comment: Thank you it works perfectly now! Such a time saver!

Comment: You can also use [Queryable(PageSize = X)] as well.  What happens here is the pagesize by default is 50 so you only get 50 + a continuation link.  Changing either maxtop or pagesize overrides that.