# Retrieve more than 50 rows with Azure Mobile Services Android SDK

Tags: android, azure, azure-mobile-services

I often have more than 50 rows in the tables that I want to return from my Azure Mobile Service to my Android app, and I have created the following function for downloading an entire table:

```
private void genericPagedLoad(final int count, final Query baseQuery, final MobileServiceSyncTable table) {
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        int takenCount = 0;
        int top = 50;
        while (takenCount < count) {
            Query query = baseQuery.skip(takenCount).top(top);
            try {
                table.pull(query).get();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            takenCount += top;
        }
        return null;
    }
}.execute();
```

}

which I call with

```
ListenableFuture<MobileServiceList<Level>> future = mClient.getTable(Level.class).where().includeInlineCount().execute();
Futures.addCallback(future, new FutureCallback<MobileServiceList<Level>>() {
@Override
public void onSuccess(MobileServiceList<Level> levels) {
    int count = levels.getTotalCount();
    Query q = mClient.getTable(Level.class).where();
    genericPagedLoad(count, q, mLevelTable);
}

@Override
public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
}
});
```

However, I would like to download the data in larger chunks than 50, but if I change my variable `top` to ex. 100 it will still only download 50 rows and then skip 100 rows. According to [this article](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-android-add-paging-data/) it should be possible to specify the number of rows with the `top()` function (up to 1000 rows), but this apparently does not work as it should. I am using the Azure Android SDK 2.0.1-beta. Is there any way to make the `top()` function work as specified?

Comment: What backend type are you using?  Most likely you should see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678904/azure-mobile-service-paging-limitation/25690332#25690332

Comment: You are right, this solves it. I had no idea that the documentation was only for Node.js backends

Comment: Can u post the solution which solved ur problem? I am also planning to write the genericPagedLoad similar to u. Just passing top more than 50 solved ur problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the top() function like following and it'll return more than 50 rows(1000 at MAX):

```
mClient.GetTable(Level.class).where().top(150).execute(...
```